# What is the link file limit using Visual Studio's link.exe?

Tags: visual-studio, linker

I know some linkers have a limit of how many object files are allowed on the command line. What is Visual Studio's? Also, if you exceed this number, some linkers allow you to specify a file containing the name of all the object files, and you would only pass that as an argument. Here's an example to show you what I mean:

```
some_linker file1.o file2.o ... file9000.o -out=some.lib
```

Suppose 9000 is too much for this linker, but it allows you to write the path to the objects in another file, `example.txt`:

```
file1.o
file2.o
...
file9000.o
```

And the linker call becomes:

```
some_linker -input=example.txt -out=some.lib
```

How is Visual Studio behaving in this situation? Does it allow for something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum number of arguments doesn't appear to be specified in that portion of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx5b050y.aspx). I'm not sure if this is provided elsewhere, but I personally haven't seen it.

However, link.exe *does* allow you to specify a text file containing the name of all the object files, which it calls a "command file". According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xch38h8.aspx), you specify a command file by prepending its filename with an at sign:

```
LINK @commandfile
```

The arguments in the command file can be separated by either spaces or tabs (as on the command line) and by newline characters.

Comment: The command line length limit is 32K, 8K when run from cmd.exe.  A file passed with @ is called a 'response file'.  Which is the way the linker is run from the IDE.