# How to link large C++-Project in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, linker

I am currently working on a very large C++-Project in my company. My job is to build a code generator for certain parts of the project. The Project is managed in Kinetis Design Studio 3.0.0 which is based on Eclipse. The Compiler used is GNU ARM C/C++ Cross Compiler 1.12.1

Now my problem is: As the number of files my generator created increased, suddenly an error message appeared:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./00_Hmi/FontsHandler/SEGE_UI_11B.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [CDSB_AutoGen.elf] Error 1
```

The message pops up when the linker tries to link all the object files to the final binary. The file that is not found by the linker does definitely exist.
If I exclude some files from the build the error disappears (obviously I have to fix some includes and parts of the code that depend on those files). It doesn't seem to matter which files I exclude. I can include all the generated files and just exclude some others. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689510/what-is-the-link-file-limit-using-visual-studios-link-exe) that linkers have a maximum number of object files that can be passed in the command line. I couldn't find that limit for GCC C++-Linker but I believe this could be the problem. The compiler creates around 160 Object files but I am not sure if all of them are used in that final link stage. I am not an expert with make or with how Eclipse handles these things. But IF my guess is correct: Is there any way to tell the linker to use all the Object files?

EDIT:
I renamed the folder that contains most of the files. The linker command got way shorter and now it works fine. I may have to either use shorter filenames or pack some of the .cpp files together.

Comment: is eclipse tag relevant here?

Comment: I guess... Since eclipse manages the g++ calls. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can also reorganise your project structure and chop sources into a bunch of static libraries linked together at the end of the building process. This will help to reduce the size of final linkage command.